# Using ThemeProvider props in Global Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

How can I access the `ThemeProvider` `props` in `global.js` when using **[styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)**?

For example in theme.js I have `${props => props.theme.fonts.fontSize}` calling a default font size of `16px`

```
const theme = {
    fonts: {
        fontSize : '16px',
    }
}

export default theme
```

This is provided in `/layouts/index.js` as

```
import React from 'react'

import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import '../style/global';
import theme from '../style/theme'

class Template extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
        {children()}
        ...
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default Template
```

From here I can access the `${props => props.theme.fonts.fontSize}` within each component or child page.

But how can I pass to `global.js` in the same way when global is technically a level above `theme.js`? So that I could create a global style as

```
injectGlobal`
  html {
    font-size: (${props => props.theme.fonts.fontSize} / 16px) * 1em;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way off solving this is by creating a top level component that injects your desired styling like this:

```
import { Children } from 'react';
import { withTheme, injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalComponent = ({ theme, children }) => {
  injectGlobal`
      font-size: ${theme.fonts.fontSize}
    }
  `;
  return Children.only(children);
};

export default withTheme(Global);
```

This will make sure all Components that have this Component as a parent will have the desired globalStyling. Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense but would it pass to values such as `html` or just the top level component that would be below `html`?

Comment: Normally `injectGlobal` takes care off that, i'd say try it with an obvious example like `background-color: 'pink'`. That makes sure you have an obvious visual queue it works.

Comment: Just trying now. Quick questions... what is meant by `withTheme`? Wouldn't that require being defined?

Comment: `withTheme` is exported by `styled-components` it is a HighOrder component that injects theme into props. Sorry i forgot to mention that import.

Comment: Added imports for you, makes sure you use the right things :) good luck with your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I assume by `withTheme(Global);` is meant to be `withTheme(GlobalComponent);` as `Global` is not defined. If so, the code passes with zero errors and works perfectly.

Comment: Now to figure out how to add another style file to handle animation mixins. Loving styled components over Sass but switching mid project is a nightmare. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh dear. It appeared to be working but I think my excitement got the best of me. It is likely as I have `GlobalComponent` in a seperate file but it is showing in console as `    font-size: (function (props) { return props.theme.fonts.fontSize; } / 16px) * 1em;`

Comment: Note that the injectGlobal API will be removed and replaced by `createGlobalStyle` in styled-components `v4`.

Answer (score 1):

Late but now we can actually create a Global Component and pass it as a child of `ThemeProvider`. It will allow you to access all the props of current `theme`.

Example for applying font family:

Your `Global.js / Global.ts`

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`

  html,
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.family}
  }

  a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`;

export default GlobalStyle;
```

Your Main component `app.tsx / app.jsx`

```
import theme...
import { ThemeProvider } ...
imort GlobalStyle from '../path-to-global-file';

const App ...
.
.
return(
 <>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <GlobalStyle />
   { /* Root component */ }
   <Component/>
  </ThemeProvider>
 </>
);
```

You can use the props easily now.